# Selecting what blocks are allowed in core/edit-widgets by sidebar ID

Tags: theme-development, widgets, block-editor

I am looking to control what blocks are available to the user in the "block-based widget area". I see this as the perfect area for handling things such as contact numbers, and alert messages (previously, I would have used an ACF options page for this).

When I setup a custom theme I control what blocks are available to the user via the `allowed_block_types_all` hook. As this offers the `$editor_context` I have used this to identify when I am in the widgets editor, like so:

```php
function bwp_allowed_blocks( $allowed_block_types, $editor_context ) {
    if(isset($editor_context->name) && 'core/edit-widgets' === $editor_context->name) {
        return array(
            'core/paragraph',
        );
    }
}
add_filter( 'allowed_block_types_all', 'bwp_allowed_blocks', 10, 2 );
```

This appears to work correctly and only gives me access to, in this example, the `core/paragraph` block.

However, I intended to register a number of different sidebars:

```php
function bwp_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Alert area',
        'id'            => 'alert_area',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    ) );

  register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Second area',
        'id'            => 'second_area',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'bwp_widgets_init' );
```

What I do not seem to be able to do is target block selection by sidebar area. From what I can tell `core/edit-widgets` is a block on its own that allows inner blocks and it displays the sidebar areas. So the allowed blocks can only be assigned to `core/edit-widgets` and not to the sidebars.

Has anyone come across a similar problem and found a solution to it?

Comment: I don't currently have an answer to your question, but I wanted to tell you that your `bwp_allowed_blocks` function needs to return the `$allowed_block_types` array, after the `if` block ends..